# how to use one model for two different forms?

Tags: yii, yii-components

I am  currently working in `yii`, I have designed a user module which consists `user registraion`, `user login` & `change password rule`.
for these three process I have designed only one `model` i.e. `user model`. in this model I have defined a rule:

```
array('email, password, bus_name, bus_type', 'required'),
```

This rule is valid for `actionRegister`. but now I want to define a new `required rule` for `actionChangePassword`,

```
array('password, conf_password', 'required'),
```

How can I define rule for this action ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rules can be associated with *scenarios*](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#rules-detail). A certain rule will only be used if the model's current `scenario` property says it should.

Sample model code:

```php
class User extends CActiveRecord {

  const SCENARIO_CHANGE_PASSWORD = 'change-password';

  public function rules() {
    return array(
      array('password, conf_password', 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CHANGE_PASSWORD), 
    );
  }

}
```

Sample controller code:

```php
public function actionChangePassword() {
  $model = $this->loadModel(); // load the current user model somehow
  $model->scenario = User::SCENARIO_CHANGE_PASSWORD; // set matching scenario

  if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest && isset($_POST['User'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
    if($model->save()) {
      // success message, redirect and terminate request
    }
    // otherwise, fallthrough to displaying the form with errors intact
  }

  $this->render('change-password', array(
    'model' => $model,
  ));
}
```